# How do I add DOM elements in jasmine tests without using external html files?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm writing some simple jasmine tests and I'm getting an exception since the code I'm testing is looking for a form that doesn't exist because there's no DOM when testing a js file only: `$("form")[0]` in the tested js file leads to:

```
TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined
```

I read a bit about jasmine-jquery and realized I can use some html fixture with an external html file. That flow seems quite messy, since all I need to do is only to add an empty valid form so that the test (which focusing on something else) will run, something like `<form></form>` appending would be enough I think.

At first I thought that sandbox() function will be the solution, but it seems that it creates only divs, and I need a form.

Any simple way to add some elements by using only code in jasmine spec file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add the form to the DOM by yourself in the before block and then delete it in the after block:

```
describe(function(){
  var form;

  beforeEach(function(){
    form = $('<form>');
    $(document.body).append(form);
  });

  it('your test', function(){


  })

  afterEach(function(){
   form.remove();
   form = null;
  });
});
```

Also writing your sandbox helper isn't that hard:

```
function sandbox(html){
  var el;

  beforeEach(function(){
    el = $(html);
    $(document.body).append(el);
  });


  afterEach(function(){
   el.remove();
   el = null;
});
```

Comment: For some reason I thought html appending won't work since I was sure that there's no DOM, only javascript. Your answer seems so trivial. Oh well. @Andreas-Köberle

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue of the focus event handler not firing.

Comment: How is the sandbox helper called? Do you just call it manually in the `describe()` block?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [jasmine fixture](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture)

> The concept
>
> Here's one way to think about it:
>
> In jQuery, you give $() a CSS selector and it finds elements on the
>   DOM.
>
> In jasmine-fixture, you give affix() a CSS selector and it adds those
>   elements to the DOM.
>
> This is very useful for tests, because it means that after setting up
>   the state of the DOM with affix, your subject code under test will
>   have the elements it needs to do its work.
>
> Finally, jasmine-fixture will help you avoid test pollution by tidying
>   up and remove everything you affix to the DOM after each spec runs.

See also: [SO: dom manipulation in Jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672389/testing-dom-manipulating-in-jasmine-test)

Comment: best answer by far, fixtures will let you work as in the original html

Answer (score 0):

You should use sandbox() to create a div and create a form element and append to sandbox, this is the safer way to jasmine take control to this fixtures in the DOM.