# document.createElement in jasmine.js

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine

When I try to run this code in jasmine.js test

```
document.createElement(tag);
```

I get this error

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I understand, the `document` object is not available in jasmine.js tests, but how can I dynamically create a new HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsdom`

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
var element = jsdom('<div></div>').querySelector('div');
```

Answer (score -1):

*Document* object is not part of JavaScript, it's browser's feature. 
Check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281937/how-do-i-add-dom-elements-in-jasmine-tests-without-using-external-html-files)

Comment: Please do not just answer with a link to another answer. If the question is the same, flag as a duplicate. If the questions are different, but he answer is similar, copy the content of the answer here, **with changes specific to this question**, and **make sure to attribute the original author**.